# I got an error of input type when I use Bayesopt function of Bayesian Optimization Toolbox

Tags: optimization, bayesian, bayesian-deep-learning

I am trying to use Bayesopt for a very simple problem and finding the minimum value of a function

```
fun = @(x) (x - 3)^2 + 5;

xvar = optimizableVariable('x',[-10,10]);
% Modify the range:
xvar.Range = [1,5];

fun = @(x)(x - 3)^2 + 5;
results = bayesopt(myfunction,xvar,'Verbose',0,...
    'AcquisitionFunctionName','expected-improvement-plus')
```

Undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type 'table'.

Error in Untitled12 (line 5)
fun = @(x)(x - 3)^2 + 5;

Would you please help me to resolve this?

I expect to get the minimum value of the dunction and I tried to change the type of variable, but I think the correct type is what I have already set up

Answer (score 0):

Your objective function doesn't accept a table, it expects constants. Perhaps you meant:

```
fun = @(x)(x{:, :} - 3)^2 + 5;
```